# Branches created by one user not seen by others

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project using Visual Studio Online (VSO) and Git on a Visual Studio 2013

I've been creating several branches that are showing up on VSO in my account or anyone elses

However in Visual Studio, no one can see my branches, and I can't see anyone elses

I've checked that all branches are published (thus in VSO), I've also checked the Permissions, and even if I add another user as Administrator for that branch, he is not able to see it

How can I fix this? Using branches that no one can see just makes the whole thing useless (kind of)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VSO, just with plain Git, but will try to guess anyway.

In Git, any *local* repository (that is, your's and each your collaborator's) is completely self-sufficient and freestanding. What this means is that a branch is only even created in it if you *explicitly* tell Git you want this—one way or the other.

Collaborating through a repository hosted somewhere everyone has access to is a convenient workflow in many situations (though certainly not sole) but it does not somehow turn Git into a centralized VCS: you might push your branches to such a repository, and your collaborators might fetch them from there but for them, these branches won't be *directly* available in their local repositories.  Instead, when they receive the branches you've pushed, their Git processes create the so-called "remote branches" in their local repositories—sort of bookmarks to the state of branches seen in a remote repository the last time it has been accessed.

Typically, a repo cloned from somewhere has one "remote" configured in it, called "origin", and when the user fetches from "origin", any remote branches created from that remote are placed under the "origin" prefix: say, "master" is saved as "origin/master" etc.  For a remote named "foo" that would be "foo/master" etc.  You can see all the branches known in your local repository using `git branch -a` and only the remote branches using `git branch -r`.

I know this *is* confusing for newcomers but again try to first fully grasp the two-fold idea:

- Your local repository is sacred: only your explicit commands might do something to the branches *you* created.
- You are free to fetch history from *any* Git repository at all, and from any number of such repositories, and they do not need to host the same project (that is, they might have completely different histories).

Now it's time to [read up on remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) and then [refine your knowledge](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

Answer (score 0):

To add to kostix's answer: you have to refresh your local master branch from the remote master branch to see new remote branches. In Visual Studio, right-click on the local master branch and select **Fetch**. You should see all new remote branches shortly after the update is completed.